# Do not allow users to downvote a question they have answered

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting, answers

I don't see a reason why it would be useful to do both of these actions so it makes sense to me to put this in place. Of course I'm curious as to why you think it makes sense as I'm suspicious it happens a lot...

Comment: Just because you answer a question doesn't mean the question doesn't suck. Sometimes not so good questions can attract super awesome answers. Also, your claim that you think this happens a lot is pure random conjecture.

Comment: I can't fully respect your answer since you posted it as a comment.

Comment: @kraftydevil It's possible that no one has pointed out to you yet that up/downvotes on Meta are not treated the same way as on the "main" Arqade site.  You will note that you'll get a lot more downvotes here, since up/down votes have no effect on your rep on Meta.  Is the "common" scenario you are referring to for questions asked on Meta, or on the main Arqade site?  Is your suspicion based on your personal experience with your first few questions, or based on research of other existing questions.  Including a link or links to example might help.

Answer (score 9):

Just because you answer a question doesn't mean the question doesn't suck. Sometimes not so good questions can attract super awesome answers.

Comment: Putting this here so the question doesn't bump

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what @badp mentioned, it would also require special handling for corner cases. Let's say someone asks a good question and you answer it. Then they edit their question into a less stellar form. Should you not be able to downvote it? Should you be required to delete your answer first? Worrying about this isn't really worth the effort.

Besides, it's important to remember that a downvote is not the same as a close vote. A downvote says "I don't like this question." Maybe you had a lot of typos. Maybe you insulted their favorite TV show. Maybe they think it didn't show much research. Maybe they are just trying to get their downvote count up. It doesn't really matter why they downvoted it... they don't have to justify that behavior. But it doesn't mean it's a question that doesn't belong on the site or doesn't deserve an answer. That distinction is reserved for *closed* questions.